# Q : Python Spell Checker using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, spell-checking

So i have this line of code using NLTK library

```
def autospell(text):
        spells = [spell(w) for w in (nltk.word_tokenize(text))]
        return " ".join(spells) 
train_data['Phrase'][:200].apply(autospell)
```

And i got this error telling me that the name spell is not defined, i dont know whats that mean because i thought it was from the NLTK library, or am i missing something somewhere?

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-582bf5662c88> in <module>()
      5         spells = [spell(w) for w in (nltk.word_tokenize(text))]
      6         return " ".join(spells)
----> 7 train_data['Phrase'][:200].apply(autospell)

2 frames
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-119-582bf5662c88> in <listcomp>(.0)
      3         correct the spelling of the word.
      4         """
----> 5         spells = [spell(w) for w in (nltk.word_tokenize(text))]
      6         return " ".join(spells)
      7 train_data['Phrase'][:200].apply(autospell)

NameError: name 'spell' is not defined
```

Comment: Well, the code is calling a function named `spell()`; where is it declared?

Comment: the previous function was this:
```
!pip install nltk
from autocorrect import Speller
def word_tokenize(text):
        return nltk.word_tokenize(text) 
```
Im not sure of which that function spell was from the library or was it supposed to be from me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Spell Checker for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928155/spell-checker-for-python), you should probably use `autocorrect` library.
Example code :

```
from autocorrect import Speller

spell = Speller(lang='en')

def autospell(text):
        spells = [spell(w) for w in (nltk.word_tokenize(text))]
        return " ".join(spells) 
train_data['Phrase'][:200].apply(autospell)
```

Comment: Ah yes i missed 1 line thanks <3
spell = Speller(lang='en')